# Hibernate does not populate generated @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp on entity with composite ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I am using JPA and Hibernate 5.

Normally, if an java bean is saved by Hibernate, I expect all the persisted values, including those generated ones, like ID, by database or by code, are populated on the *original* entity. By saying "generated values", I am refering either generated ID by `@PerPersist` method(if is a UUID I do it this way), or `@GeneratedValue` with a dedicated sequence in database; also, I refer to timestamps generated by `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp`, who are responsible for filling a timestamp into a field when a row is inserted/updated.

**And this actually works when the entity has simple `@Id` field.**

But, when I have a bean with composite id, and when the composite id is another `@Embeddable` bean, the creation timestamp and update timestamp is done correctly and persisted in DB, but not populated into the original entity.

The entity with composite ID:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "balance_transaction")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class BalanceTransaction {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositeIdMerchantProvider compositeIdMerchantProvider;

    @Column(name = "rate")
    private Integer rate;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created")
    private OffsetDateTime created;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "modified")
    private OffsetDateTime modified;
}
```

The embeddable id bean:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CompositeIdMerchantProvider implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "merchant_id")
    private Short merchantId;

    @Column(name = "provider_id")
    private Short providerId;
}
```

In the test, I first save a `Provider`, then a `Merchant`, then take the ID out, and assign them to the ID bean, and set it to `BalanceTransaction`, and save it to DB.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    resetMerchant(); // create instance, set values, etc.
    resetProvider(); // create instance, set values, etc.
    resetBalanceTransaction(); // create instance, set values, etc.
    merchantRepository.save(merchant); // NOTE: here `merchant` has all the values saved to DB; I don't have to assign the returned one to another entity of type `Merchant`, i.e., they are populated correctly.
    providerRepository.save(provider); // NOTE: this also applies to `provider`
    composite.setProviderId(provider.getId());
    composite.setMerchantId(merchant.getId());
    balanceTransaction.setCompositeIdMerchantProvider(composite);
}
```

Note that `Merchant` and `Provider` both have a `Short` type `@Id`, generated by a dedicated sequence of a Postgresql database. And, they both have these fields:

For example, `Merchant`:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Entity
@Table(name = "merchant")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id", "transactions"})
@ToString(exclude = {"transactions"})
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Merchant implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="merchant_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="merchant_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Short id; // limited possibilities

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name; // mandatory, max 45 characters

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Boolean status; // whether merchant is active or not

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created")
    private OffsetDateTime created;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "modified")
    private OffsetDateTime modified;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // the name of property at "many" end
    private Set<Transaction> transactions;


    /**
     * Add Transaction to the set; must be called after any of two constructors,
     * because we need to initialize the set first.
     * @param t Transaction entity to add
     */
    public void addTransaction(Transaction t) {
        if (transactions == null) {
            transactions = new HashSet<>();
        }
        this.transactions.add(t);
        t.setMerchant(this);
    }

    /**
     * Remove an <code>Transaction</code> from the list of this class.
     * Caution: {@link Set#iterator()#remove()} does not work when iterating. We must
     * construct a new Set and {@link #setTransactions(Set)} again.
     * @param t the <code>Transaction</code> to remove.
     */
    public void removeTransaction(Transaction t) {
        setTransactions(
                transactions.stream().filter(x -> !x.equals(t)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new))
        );
    }

}
```

And when saved, the timestamps are created and populated into the original entity.

But, it seems that this does not work for this test:

```
@Test
public void givenABalanceTransactionEntity_WhenISaveItIntoDb_ShouldReturnSavedBalanceTransactionEntity() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    //given (in @Before)

    //when
    serviceClient.saveBalanceTransaction(balanceTransaction); // <-------- "balanceTransaction" will not have timestamp populated

    //then
    Assert.assertNotNull(balanceTransaction); // <-------- this line passes
    Assert.assertNotNull(balanceTransaction.getCreated()); // <------- this line does not pass
    Assert.assertNotNull(balanceTransaction.getModified()); // <------- this neither

    // cleanup
    repository.delete(balanceTransaction);

}
```

If I do

```
BalanceTransaction saved = serviceClient.saveBalanceTransaction(balanceTransaction);
```

and check `saved`, this test does not fail.

So:

populated saved values into the *original* entity, is not a standard? Is very failure-prone? It seems that it does not guarantee anything.

Comment: NPE normally means that the instance is null on which you call the methods. That would mean that `balanceTransaction` is null

Comment: No, note the previous line passes. I have used the debugger and the timestamp is null.

Comment: You call `balanceTransaction.setCompositeIdMerchantProvider(composite);` where `composite` only has the id's of provider and merchant. How you come to think that `balanceTransaction.getCreated()` should be populated with a value from e.g. the merchant? Actually only on `serviceClient.saveBalanceTransaction(balanceTransaction);` the creation and update timestamp are to be created and set. Though they should be saved in the database. I am not sure if the values are populated on the client side, but it should work if you refresh the `balanceTransaction` before asserting

Comment: Maybe I was not clear; look, both `Merchant` and `BalanceTransaction` has two fields, `created` and `updated`, and they are both annotated with `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp`, who should be responsible for filling the current timestamp in table when insert/update. And, I see in `Merchant`, these timestamps are populated to the original entity. In `Merchant`, when saving, this is happening. But in `BalanceTransaction`, when saving, this is not happening. And I suspect it is due to the composite ID field in `BalanceTransaction`.

Comment: Not sure about your transactions, but it could very well be, that you unit test never actually writes to the database so you never could be able to see the values there. Without knowing what exactly `saveBalanceTransaction()` does, its hard to tell what the issue could be. If I understand you right, you already know what you need to (`refresh the entity`). I have the feeling you mix database data with local data. Actually I am pretty sure, that you do anything in `saveBalanceTransaction()` which makes it fail

Comment: I was debugging, and I see timestamp saved to database. Maybe a gif would do. Wait a second.

Comment: Better post the code on how you save the balanceTransaction. So basically the call chain starting from `serviceClient.saveBalanceTransaction(balanceTransaction);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189953/discussion-between-westerngun-and-xtremebaumer).

Comment: Any definitive answer on this? I'm not able to see the chat history, even when I have enough reputation for doing it :(

Comment: @chomp no, as I remember there was not. The chat history is lost, though. At last I keep using the returned entity and it is fine.

Comment: Got it. I had a similar situation, and I end up using saveAndFlush(...) instead of just save(...). That small difference solved the problem in my case.

Comment: That is not my solution because I also tried `saveAndFlush()` but that will not for complex case like composite entities like mine.